# In what countries is it possible to enter a life science PhD program directly after a Bachelor's?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters

I would like to know which countries allow admission to a PhD program directly after finishing a Bachelor's (Life Science), without requiring an intervening Master's degree?

And if you go directly into a PhD after the B.S., which countries support it? In India(my country), it is nearly impossible other than you join a integrated course.

Is it same everywhere?

Comment: So having a bachelors degree in india makes it impossible to get a PhD? That seems a bit weird.

Comment: @Neo: In most countries other than the US, UK, and Canada, it's very difficult to get admission to a PhD program without already having a master's degree.

Comment: These questions may help you: [PhD in Germany after Bachelors](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16035/phd-in-germany-after-bachelors) and [Applying to Ph.D. with 5 years in Bachelors](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11187/applying-to-ph-d-with-5-years-in-bachelors)

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so this isn't the place for an "open to all stream discussion". Please edit your question to be a lot more specific.

Comment: I edited for clarity.

Comment: In addition to @EnergyNumbers comment, this would likely vary by university rather than by country.

Answer (score 2):

In general, applying for a Ph.D. program in life sciences with just a bachelor's degree is possible in at least some of the US universities (I do not know, however, to which extent this affects your chances at acceptance).

E.g. the Harvard medical school web site says ["Minimal requirements include a bachelor’s degree and undergraduate preparation in the sciences."](http://www.gsas.harvard.edu/programs_of_study/division_of_medical_sciences_at_harvard_medical_school_dms.php)